# IMAP Append for Office 365

Tags: office365, imap, outlook-restapi

I am trying to make something which involves syncing of emails across users in office 365. I am using Outlook's REST API but I cannot find any function similar to IMAP's Append in this API. (Please note I don't want to send. I want something similar to insert or push)

Also, from the response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747477/imap-auth-in-office-365-using-oauth2-mechnism) question, I found that Office 365 does not support OAuth Mechanism for IMAP. So I cannot use Outlook OAuth2.0 to connect to IMAP.

Is there any way to connect to office365 account with IMAP without a password or to push email using Outlook REST API?

Comment: The comments on that question cast some doubt on whether it does or not.  The current CAPABILITY string indicates support for XOAUTH2,  which is currently documented here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol

Comment: The link you provided gives a way to access gmail accounts using OAuth token and IMAP. However, the same mechanism fails if we switch to outlook. IMAP is supported but not through OAuth mechanism for Office365.

Comment: Well, they're either working on it or left it half implemented because the server says it supports XOAUTH2 authentication in its IMAP CAPABILITY string.  Maybe you need a special scope.

Comment: Yes, for IMAP wl.imap and wl.offline_access scope are required, but when included while requesting the access token, we receive a bad request error. IMAP works fine if connected using username password though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I figured it out later that there is no way to authorize outlook 365 accounts without username and password. Hence, to use IMAP.Append, one has to provide username and password.