# Connect to outlook Office 365 IMAP using OAUTH2

Tags: email, outlook, oauth-2.0, office365, imap

Referred https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api.
Still I couldn't understand the AD, Outlook and windows live.

I got refresh token and access token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

and the scope

> openid email profile offline_access 
>   https://outlook.office.com/mail.send 
>   https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite

Still i m getting error while connect imap using the access token.

```
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', 'xxxxxxx', access_token)
Net::IMAP::NoResponseError: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747477/imap-auth-in-office-365-using-oauth2

No Support for Oauth2 for IMAP. Is it true?

Comment: Sad, but true...

Answer (score 3):

I have finally gotten this to work. 
Interestingly I had to use the scope `https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` although by now you have to register your app under the Graph API section in the Azure AD and the proposed Scope is `https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` which did not work for me (Authentication failed).
Though I am not sure if that will change in the near future.

I used the properties as stated here: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2

```
props.put("mail.imap.sasl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
```

Comment: Thanks, that is also I was looking for, but I faced different problem.
This (graph) scope works with office365 accounts, while gives an error - invalid scope, if I login with personal Microsoft account, how this can be resolved?
Or for personal accounts, I need to use different scopes and oath2 endpoints?

Comment: With personal accounts you refer to outlook.com accounts? I have not tested those but assumed they should work alike. I would assume that you have to use a different endpoint and probably a different scope. Haven't found any documentation on that yet.

Comment: Yes. I'm able to use different endpoints - login.live.com. But them are already not recommended by MS in the documentation. That is why I asking.
Also I just found out that  - https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser do not work for me.
Scope is invalid it says :(

Comment: I have voted this answer down because it does not work with the official scope IMAP.AccessAsUser.All and the scope IMAP.AccessAsUser does not exist anymore. This will likely save some people the trouble trying this. Apparently OAuth for IMAP/SMTP is still a work in progress.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have adjusted the answer above as the ```.All``` at the end of the first mentioned scope was missing. I agree, this is not a final solution and hopefully the scope as shown in the Azure directory starting with graph will be used but as of now it does not work. Unfortunately we cannot wait longer for the final solution so we have to work with what is present now. Maybe you can edit your comment so it is more clear which scopes we are talking about, the difference is the Prefix URL, the ```IMAP.AccessAsUser.All``` part is actually identical.

Comment: Seems that none of the scopes worked for me. @mrudolf, would you mind checking my question if I made some mistake there? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61597263/1126831

Answer (score 1):

**For those asking about IMAP for personal accounts -- Outlook.com**
-- re: [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473858/connect-to-outlook-office-365-imap-using-oauth2/61107041#comment107683802_60773366)

Apparently the scopes for the consumer Outlook.com (also live.com) is `wl.imap`.
See old Microsoft doc on [Scopes and permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh243646).

- Update: see also newer Microsoft doc [Using Windows Live scopes and Outlook REST API to access Outlook.com mailbox data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/use-outlook-rest-api#using-windows-live-scopes-and-outlook-rest-api-to-access-outlookcom-mailbox-data)

Also have a look at this example where the same scope is mentioned:
http://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/OAuth2MicrosoftRegularAccountsInstalledApps.html

BTW, we came across the old Microsoft doc from *Clever Components* article:

https://www.clevercomponents.com/articles/article049/

- *note: their claim this is for Office365 may be questionable, perhaps a documentation error on their part*

which has a link to a Microsoft doc:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dn440163

which has a link to `Scopes and permissions` in the related section listed at the end of the page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh243646

In the *Clever Components* article, they used two scopes `wl.imap` and `wl.offline_access`.
They noted that:

> Microsoft recommends to use the "wl.offline_access" scope together with "wl.imap". Otherwise, an app can access the user's info only when a user signs in to Live Connect and uses your app."

So if your application needs continuous access then you need to include the offline access scope.

Comment: This may be useful: Using Microsoft Hotmail/LIVE OAUTH + IMAP 
 https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/sdk/?ct=object_oauth_live_a

Comment: I'd recommend this link https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/OAuth2MicrosoftRegularAccountsInstalledApps.html (without ms prefix in the domain, that one causes false positive with my Kaspersky for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

See latest Microsoft announcement on April 30, 2020.

[Announcing OAuth 2.0 support for IMAP, SMTP client protocols in Exchange Online](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/announcing-oauth-2-0-support-for-imap-smtp-client-protocols-in-exchange-online/)

> Today, we’re announcing the availability of [OAuth 2.0 authentication for IMAP, SMTP AUTH protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth) to Exchange Online mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

This made for an exceedingly frustrating experience in my own OAuth IMAP implementation as [Microsoft's own documentation on this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth) still advises to use endpoints such as `offline_access` and `https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All`.

However [when trying to register a new application in the Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade) and going to the "API permissions" sidebar tab and selecting "Add a permission" the "Request API permissions" sidebar-popup has no mention of `Office 365 Exchange Online` anywhere. It can be found tucked away under the "APIs my organization uses" tab and selecting it from the list but inside there is no Application nor Delegated permission matching `IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` despite this being the appropriate section for all `https://outlook.office.com/*` API endpoints.

In the end, it turns out you must use the large "Microsoft Graph" API button at the top of the "Request API Permissions" screen and select both `offline_access` and `IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` from there. **But do not use the graphs.microsoft.com URL it enables**. Continue using the Scope string: `offline_access https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` for those two and OAuth will work when authenticating as the email address used to authenticate in the OAuth popup.

Despite `IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` this alone is not enough to allow an account to send using a different `From:` address after getting an OAuth token. The OAuth token is also only valid for the email address which were used to generate the OAuth bearer token for the application. Further permissions must be delegated to touch other mailboxes.