# OAUTH with O365 account and use the token for IMAP manipulation for web platform

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, microsoft-graph-api, imap

I can see that [Microsoft is in a process](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/improving-security-together/ba-p/805892) of rolling out official support for OAUTH support for IMAP requests. I want to access this functionality now. There are few proposed solutions, but they are using hacks and undocumented features or simply fail.

[Using Microsoft Hotmail/LIVE OAUTH + IMAP](https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/sdk/?ct=object_oauth_live_a)  - Here, when I add `EWS.AccessAsUser.All` to scope in OAuth requesst, I get `{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. ... }`. The probable reason is that this solution is for personal outlook (not O365) accounts and for desktop app.

[Using login.live.com auth endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473858/connect-to-outlook-office-365-imap-using-oauth2/60773366#60773366) - Not working for me using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` auth endpoint.

Are you aware of any documented, safe method of connecting to `outlook.office365.com` using oauth tokens acquired from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You are using client credentials grant flow which is not supported.

For alternative You can use any of these

1. [OAuth2 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)
2. [OAuth2 Device authorization grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code)

If you would still looking to use Client credentials the grant flow we recommend you to use the [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) which allow access without a user.