# python read outlook emails with oauth2

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, office365, imap

I've been using basic auth to log in to my outlook email with imap.

```
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap-mail.outlook.com")
# authenticate
imap.login(username, password)
status, messages = imap.select("INBOX")
```

Now that Microsoft moved to oauth2 I'm getting "Login failed" messages even although the credentials are correct.
Can anyone share a code example that connects with oauth2?

I found this guide, but it only shows the steps on the account side, not the actual connection in the app.
[https://docs.emailengine.app/setting-up-oauth2-with-outlook/#:~:text=Navigate%20to%20Configuration-%3EOAuth2%20and,of%20accounts%20your%20application%20supports](https://docs.emailengine.app/setting-up-oauth2-with-outlook/#:%7E:text=Navigate%20to%20Configuration-%3EOAuth2%20and,of%20accounts%20your%20application%20supports).

Thanks

Comment: This seems to do the trick:
[office-365-imap-authentication-via-oauth2-and-python-msal-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902642/office-365-imap-authentication-via-oauth2-and-python-msal-library)

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution,

1. follow this guide to create an app with necessary permissions.

https://docs.emailengine.app/setting-up-oauth2-with-outlook/#:%7E:text=Navigate%20to%20Configuration-%3EOAuth2%20and,of%20accounts%20your%20application%20supports

2. use the following code in your app.

   imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host, 993)

   imap.debug = 4

   access_token = get_access_token_to_authenticate_imap()

   imap.authenticate("XOAUTH2", lambda x:generate_auth_string(
   'useremail',
   access_token['access_token']))

   imap.select('inbox')