# Problem with Authentication for Microsoft 365 (Oauth2) Authentication failed // Python IMAP

Tags: python

i got a question for the Authentication with Outlook for Microsoft 365.
I got this Line of Code

```
import imaplib
import msal


# Konfiguration
client_id = 'client_id'
tenant_id = 'tenand_id'
client_secret = 'client_secret'
username = 'test@mail.com'

# Authentifizierung
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
)

def generate_auth_string(username, token):
    return f"user={username}\x01auth=Bearer{token}\x01\x01" 

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=['https://outlook.office365.com/.default'])



#IMAP-Verbindung
mailserver = 'outlook.office365.com'
imapport = 993
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(mailserver,imapport)
M.authenticate('XOAUTH2', lambda x: f'user={username}\\1auth=Bearer {result["access_token"]}\\1\\1')
M.authenticate("XOAUTH2", lambda x: generate_auth_string("test@mail.com", result['access_token']).encode("utf-8"))

# Verbindung schließen
M.close()
M.logout()
```

I get the Error Message

`imaplib.IMAP4.error: AUTHENTICATE failed.`

We already signed the Application permission in the App registration and had done all steps from the answer in this question [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902642/office-365-imap-authentication-via-oauth2-and-python-msal-library](https://stackoverflow.com)](https://stackoverflow.com)

Anyone has an Idea how we can fix this Problem?

Kind regards